# multiple Y axis - margin

Tags: highcharts

I have multiple Y axis on my chart, they have no titles. I cannot find a property that would allow me to add a bit of space between the axis. Is it possible ? This is what I have now. As you can see it looks very squashed.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `offset` property.

Example:

```
  yAxis: [{
        offset: 0,
        lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
  title: { text: 0 }
    },{
        offset: 50,
        lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
  title: { text: 0 }
    },{
        offset: 100,
        lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
  title: { text: 0 }
    }]
```

(chart margin may also need to be adjusted to suit, depending on your set up)

Fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/pekhvvcq/

Reference:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.offset